# Pgfplots - Turn off Box when plotting a File

Tags: pgfplots, plot, tikz-datavisualization, filecontents

By default, pgfplots will draw a box around my plot. I am plotting a .dat-File with `\draw table [...] {data.dat}` and i want to turn that box off and just leave the x- and y-lines instead.
In the manual and other posts here on SE i found, that i can modify the box-drawing-behavior by writing

```
axis x line = bottom,
axis y line = left,
```

in the axis options. i've done so, but my plot doesn't change; it keeps the box. My guess is, that i can't modify axis when plotting from a file with the `\draw table [...]` - command, but i'm not sure if i missed something.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
  x y
  1 4
  2 3
  3 2
  4 1
  5 2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xlabel=\(x\),ylabel=\(y\)]
    \addplot table [
    x=x,
    y=y,
    axis x line = bottom,
    axis y line = left,
    ] {data.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: apparently this only works, when i use the named options globally in `pgfplotsset`! Is this normal behavior?

Comment: I have to add the options to `\axis`, not to `\addplot`! Now it works! Thanks :) @marmot

Comment: You're right. I was so focused on "not table" that I confused the two when typing (but in the example it was correct....)

Comment: Accepted your answer! Thanks for the guidance, actually this was a little dumb of a question but i'm glad that it was such a quick fix. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are feeding all these options into `table`. However, to change the **plot** you need to add them to `\begin{axis}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
  x y
  1 4
  2 3
  3 2
  4 1
  5 2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xlabel=\(x\),ylabel=\(y\),axis x line = bottom,axis y line = left]
    \addplot table [
    x=x,
    y=y] {data.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]